# Arabic/Chinese translations not working properly in Prawn - Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, fonts, multilingual, prawn

See, I've been looking for a better option to generate dynamic content in **Arabic** and **Traditional Chinese** languages in my web application using the gem `Prawn`. I tried it with **English** and **German** and are working fine. But, Arabic and Chinese are not supported..

After searching a lot, I could see that we can use particular fonts for generating the same. We need to download custom fonts and put in Prawn base directory and after creating a pdf object, we need to add this custom font by the below line:

```
pdf.font "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/fonts/custom_font.ttf" (Gem directory)
```

But, with the font types I've tried, I'm not sure whether it is exactly alike the translation I've given in my app using Google translator. For Chinese, it is a big issue.

So, can any  one of you suggest how I could get a better font for Arabic and Chinese (freely dowbloadable) and it should also support cross-browsers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use custom fonts to server your purpose:

For `Arabic`: you can use `trado.ttf`

For `Chinese`: you can use `gkai00mp.ttf`

Create a folder fonts in your `'/app/assets/'` path and add it to your `asset_path` by adding the below line in `application.rb`,

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

And for generating the Arabic/Chinese content in PDF report, please do as below.

```
pdftable = Prawn::Document.new
if I18n.locale == :ar
    #pdftable.font "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/fonts/trado.ttf"
    pdftable.font Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts', 'trado.ttf')
    pdftable.text_direction = :rtl
elsif I18n.locale == :zh
    #pdftable.font "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/fonts/gkai00mp.ttf"
     pdftable.font Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts', 'gkai00mp.ttf')
end
```

Hope you could generate reports in Arabic/Chinese languages.

Answer (score 0):

To print Arabic properly, you will need to use the following gem to transform the arabic letters into their connected readable form:

https://github.com/staii/arabic-letter-connector